# Question on scale invariant QFTs

Tags: conformal-field-theory, dimensional-analysis, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, correlation-functions

So, I have been told, but not explained, why the two-point function of the stress energy tensor, $\langle T_{zz}(x)T_{zz}(0)\rangle\propto 1/z^4$. I believe it stems from the analysis of field operators at an RG fixed point, but I can not put words to it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's more basic than that. Stress tensors have dimension $d$ and $z$ is the only dimensionful quantity in that correlation function.

Comment: @ConnorBehan then how would I argue that it is proportional 4o $z^{-4}$? Is there just something very basic I am glossing over?

Comment: You could start by deciding whether positions are $x$ or $z$. And specifying whether the person who told you about this formula also told you what spatial dimension it's supposed to hold in.